# EMR/Redshift Data Warehouse

Tags: hadoop, hive, amazon-redshift, sqoop, amazon-emr

We are currently using SQL Server in AWS. We are looking at ways to create a data warehouse from that data in SQL Server.

It seems like the easiest way was to use AWS DMS tool and send data to redshift having it constantly sync. Redshift is pretty expensive so looking at other ways of doing it.

I have been working with EMR. Currently I am using sqoop to take data from SQL Server and put it into Hive. I am currently use the HDFS volume to store data. I have not used S3 yet for that.

Our database has many tables with millions of rows in each.

What is the best way to update this data everyday? Does sqoop support updating data. If not what other tool is used for something like this.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion you can go for Hadoop clusters(EMR) if the processing is too complex and time taken process or better to use Redshift.

Choose the right tool. If it is for the data warehouse then go for Redshift.

And why DMS? are you going to sync in real-time? You want the daily sync. So no need to use DMS.

#### Better solution:

1. Make sure you have a primary key column and column that tell us when the row gets updated like `updated_at` or `modified_at`.
2. Run BCP to export the data in bulk from SQL Server to CSV files.
3. Upload the CSV to S3 then import to RedShift.
4. Use glue to fetch the incremental data (based on the primary key column and the update_at column) then export it to S3.
5. Import files from S3 to RedShift staging tables.
6. Run upsert command (update + insert) to merge the staging table with the main table.

If you feel running the glue is a bit expensive, then use SSIS or Powershell script to do steps 1 to 4. Then `psql` command to import files from S3 to Redshift and do steps 5 and 6.

This will handle the Insert and updates in your SQL server tables. But the deletes will not be a part of it. If you need all CRUD operations then go for the CDC method with DMS or Debezium. Then push it to S3 and RedShift.